# Extract nth occurrence with Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to find the best way to parse a line that looks like this:

`Explicit|00|11|Hello World|12 3 134||and|blah|blah|blah`

I just want to extract the stuff between the 6th and 7th vertical bar |
I tried something like

```
if ($line =~ /^(.*\|){6}(\w*)\|/ ) {  
    print $2;  
}
```

The problem is that the first part seems to be matching the longest sequence possible because of `.*`, perhaps there is something different I should be using. Between the vertical bars, there are alphanumeric characters, spaces and punctuation.

Should I be matching the shortest between them?

Comment: You're right. I guess I have just been playing with regex for a while so I didn't even think of using other functions :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `.*?` instead, to modify the `*` to prefer fewer to more times.

This could still match in the wrong place if the field you want has non-word characters; to prevent this you can either explicitly say anything-but-| ( `([^|]*\|){6}` ) or disable backtracking for that part ( `((?>.*?\|)){6}` ).

Or you could just use split:

```
if ( my $seventh = ( split /\|/, $line, 8 )[6] ) {
    print $seventh;
}
```

(the 8 is optional and tells split not to bother trying anymore after reaching the 7th |)

Comment: Oh, that's great. Yes, I will just use split, makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Use split. Something like `my @fields = split /\|/, $str` should work. Then you just index the field you're interested in (also empty fields will be preserved). | must be escaped as it's regexp operator.